Recursive Directory Search - Not getting the correct current working directory (Python)
I'm currently in the early stages of a course for Python, and have hit a wall and was hoping for some guidance. The problem states.


-Write a function or method called find that takes two arguments called path and dir. The path argument should accept a relative or absolute path to a directory where the search should start, while the dir argument should be the name of a directory that you want to find in the given path. Your program should display the absolute paths if it finds a directory with the given name.
The directory search should be done recursively. This means that the search should also include all subdirectories in the given path.


Example input: path="./tree", dir="python"
I wasnt able to solve it and finally took a look at the given answer but it doesnt seem to work correctly either
import os

class DirectorySearcher:
    def find(self, path, dir):
        try:
            os.chdir(path)
        except OSError:
            # Doesn't process a file that isn't a directory.
            return

        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        for entry in os.listdir("."):
            if entry == dir:
                print(os.getcwd() + "/" + dir)
            self.find(current_dir + "/" + entry, dir)


directory_searcher = DirectorySearcher()
directory_searcher.find("./tree", "python")

I created a few sample folders on my desktop and the expected output was
.../tree/python
.../tree/c/python

My output though is actually yielding
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tree\c\python
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tree\c\python\python

I had created the following folders
tree ------>c------>python
     ------>python

If I understand correctly, it looks like the code would first be able to pull up the folders [c, python]. It then goes into the c directory, finds the Python folder, tries to loop through that, and gets returned back to the next value in the list [python]. But at this point the current working directory is still the last one it traversed which is C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tree\c\python. Since the next value is [python] it just takes the last directory and tags on the [python] value at the end.
I been trying to make it work, but can't quite seem to wrap my head around how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Are you not allowed to use os.walk()?

Do not use dir as a variable name since you're shadowing a standard function

The problem is that returning from the recursion doesn't restore the working directory. You should do chdir("..") before returning.
class DirectorySearcher:
    def find(self, path, dir):
        try:
            os.chdir(path)
        except OSError:
            # Doesn't process a file that isn't a directory.
            return

        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        for entry in os.listdir("."):
            if entry == dir:
                print(os.getcwd() + "/" + dir)
            self.find(current_dir + "/" + entry, dir)
        os.chdir("..")

Or you could avoid changing the directory in the first place. You can use os.path.isdir() to test if path is a directory.
class DirectorySearcher:
    def find(self, path, dir):
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            # Doesn't process a file that isn't a directory.
            return

        for entry in os.listdir(path):
            if entry == dir:
                print(os.path.join(path, entry))
            self.find(os.path.join(path, entry), dir)
        os.chdir("..")

In this version I've also replaced the filename concatenation with os.path.join().

Thank you! I made the mistake of putting the os.chdir("..") IN the loop in the first example and it was giving me unexpected results. Didnt think to put it OUTSIDE the loop!
